# How to add qml ScatterSeries to existing qml defined ChartView?

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I am trying to add series on demand to an existing ChartView defined in qml using python. I have found an example which shows how to do this in C++ (taken from https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#createSeries-method):

```
// lineSeries is a LineSeries object that has already been added to the ChartView; re-use its axes
var myAxisX = chartView.axisX(lineSeries);
var myAxisY = chartView.axisY(lineSeries);
var scatter = chartView.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeScatter, "scatter series", myAxisX, myAxisY);
```

But I can't find a way to do this in python. Here are some snippets from my attempt so far:

QML snippet (which initially has just 1 scatter series):

```
        ChartView {
            id: bscan0
            ScatterSeries{
                id: hits0
                axisX: ValueAxis {
                    id: bscan0_xAxix
                    min: 0
                    max: 10
                }
                axisY: ValueAxis {
                    id: bscan0_yAxis
                    min: -105
                    max: 1
                }
            }
```

QML js function to pass chartView to python so it can add another series:

```
dataModel.addChartSeries(bscan0, hits0)
```

Python snippet of addChartSeries:

```
    @Slot(QObject, QObject)
    def addChartSeries(self, chartView, chart_series):
        myAxisX = chartView.axisX(chart_series) # reuse the axis from existing series
        myAxisY = chartView.axisY(chart_series) # reuse the axis from existing series

#         This function equivalent to the c++ one doesn't exit
#         myChartSeries = chartView.createSeries(QtCharts.SeriesTypeScatter, "scatter series", myAxisX, myAxisY)

#       So try another way:
        myChartSeries = QtCharts.QScatterSeries()
        myChartSeries.setName("scatter series")
        myChartSeries.attachAxis(myAxisX) 
        myChartSeries.attachAxis(myAxisY)
        myChartSeries.append(5, -10) 
        myChartSeries.append(5, -20) 
        myChartSeries.append(5, -30)

#         Try to get chart from existing series. Doesn't work
#         Error says that chart_series is not in a chart (it is!)
#         myChart = chart_series.chart()
# Series not in the chart. Please addSeries to chart first.

#         Try to get chart from chartview passed across. Doesn't work
#         Error says that object has no .chart attribute (same for .chart and .chart()):
#         myChart = chartView.chart
# Error: 'PySide2.QtQuick.QQuickItem' object has no attribute 'chart'

#         It seems I must add series to chart like this, not to chartView, 
#         but I can't find a way to get the chart for the chartView.
#         myChart.addSeries(myChartSeries)
```

The above python function is in my class "dataModel" which I pass to QML like this (the datamodel class works fine for lots of other things I do with it so no problem there):

```
    dataModel = DataModel()    
    self.rootContext().setContextProperty("dataModel", dataModel)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QML Charts API is written based on the API used by C++ but it is not the same, for example the ChartView is a QQuickItem that does not expose the QChart unlike QChartView is a QGraphicsView(QWidget) that if it exposes the QChart, what Same is with the series. In conclusion you will not be able to use C++(Python) classes to interact with QML.

The example you show at the beginning is not an example for C++ but for QML so it cannot be translated directly into QML. It is also not possible to create a QML Series in C++/Python with QtCharts classes directly, a possible strategy is to use QQmlExpression that can evaluate QML elements and return it to C++/Python. In addition, the createSeries() method not only adds the series but also connects signals.

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml

# https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtcharts.git/tree/src/chartsqml2/declarativechart_p.h#n105
class SeriesType(Enum):
    SeriesTypeLine = 0
    SeriesTypeArea = auto()
    SeriesTypeBar = auto()
    SeriesTypeStackedBar = auto()
    SeriesTypePercentBar = auto()
    SeriesTypePie = auto()
    SeriesTypeScatter = auto()
    SeriesTypeSpline = auto()
    SeriesTypeHorizontalBar = auto()
    SeriesTypeHorizontalStackedBar = auto()
    SeriesTypeHorizontalPercentBar = auto()
    SeriesTypeBoxPlot = auto()
    SeriesTypeCandlestick = auto()


class DataModel(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, engine, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.m_engine = engine

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QObject, QtCore.QObject, QtCore.QObject, result=QtCore.QObject)
    def addChartSeries(self, chart_view, chart_axis_x, chart_axis_y):
        context = QtQml.QQmlContext(self.m_engine.rootContext())
        context.setContextProperty("chart_view", chart_view)
        context.setContextProperty("axis_x", chart_axis_x)
        context.setContextProperty("axis_y", chart_axis_y)
        context.setContextProperty("type", SeriesType.SeriesTypeScatter.value)
        script = """chart_view.createSeries(type, "scatter series", axis_x, axis_y);"""
        expression = QtQml.QQmlExpression(context, chart_view, script)
        serie, valueIsUndefined = expression.evaluate()
        if expression.hasError():
            print(expression.error())
            return

        import random

        mx, Mx = chart_axis_x.property("min"), chart_axis_x.property("max")
        my, My = chart_axis_y.property("min"), chart_axis_y.property("max")
        if not valueIsUndefined:
            for _ in range(100):
                x = random.uniform(mx, Mx)
                y = random.uniform(my, My)
                serie.append(x, y)
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-scatterseries.html#borderColor-prop
            serie.setProperty("borderColor", QtGui.QColor("salmon"))
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-scatterseries.html#brush-prop
            serie.setProperty("brush", QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("green")))
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-scatterseries.html#borderColor-prop
            serie.setProperty("borderWidth", 4.0)
            return serie


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()

    dataModel = DataModel(engine)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("dataModel", dataModel)
    file = os.path.join(current_dir, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtCharts 2.2


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: bscan0
        ValueAxis {
            id: bscan0_xAxix
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: bscan0_yAxis
            min: -100
            max: 100
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var serie = dataModel.addChartSeries(bscan0, bscan0_xAxix, bscan0_yAxis)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Although the general strategy is to create the series in QML and fill it in C++/Python, for example:

```py
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml, QtCharts


class DataModel(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.Slot(QtCharts.QtCharts.QAbstractSeries)
    def fill_serie(self, serie):
        mx, Mx = 0, 10
        my, My = -100, 100
        for _ in range(100):
            x = random.uniform(mx, Mx)
            y = random.uniform(my, My)
            serie.append(x, y)
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-scatterseries.html#borderColor-prop
        serie.setProperty("borderColor", QtGui.QColor("salmon"))
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-scatterseries.html#brush-prop
        serie.setProperty("brush", QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("green")))
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-scatterseries.html#borderColor-prop
        serie.setProperty("borderWidth", 4.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()

    dataModel = DataModel(engine)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("dataModel", dataModel)
    file = os.path.join(current_dir, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtCharts 2.2


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: bscan0
        ValueAxis {
            id: bscan0_xAxix
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: bscan0_yAxis
            min: -100
            max: 100
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var serie = bscan0.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeScatter, "scatter series", bscan0_xAxix, bscan0_yAxis);
            dataModel.fill_serie(serie)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very useful, thanks. I will try creating the series in qml as per your example. I don't know how many series I need until I load up the datamodel, but it looks as if I can choose to create n new series in qml with a variation of your example. Ideally I need to remove and recreate them if the user reloads new data. I'm guessing there is a way to remove them and then attach this to a load button? Will let you know how I get on and mark it as accepted answer once I've got it working.

Comment: @BobbyG My answer is for your current question, it's not for your project, I don't know what more requirements/limitations your project has, so I can't guarantee you anything. Remember that in SO we do not help in projects (we are very limited for it), only for particular problems, IMHO acceptance of my answer should not depend on your project.

Comment: Agreed. Just want to give it a try and make sure I understand.